# SystemJS doesn't process automatically less files (Angular2)

Tags: angular, less, systemjs

I'm using SystemJS with Angular2. I've installed less systemjs plugin : 
https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-less/blob/master/README.md

My less files are loaded but less syntax is not interpretated (color aliases for example).
Here's my systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    SystemJS.config({
        baseURL: '/', 
        paths:
        {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },    
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      tsconfig: true
    },    
    map: {
      app: 'app',
      'main':                       'main.js',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript': 'npm:typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        css: 'npm:systemjs-plugin-css',
        less: 'npm:systemjs-plugin-less',
        lesscss: 'npm:less'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      'app/core': { main: 'index' },
      'app/models': { main: 'index' },
      'api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      app: {
        main: './main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      lesscss: {
          main: {
              browser: './dist/less.min.js',
              node: '@node/less'
          }
      },
      css: {
          main: 'css.js'
      },
      less: {
          main: 'less.js'
      }
    },
    meta: {
        'typescript': {
            "exports": "ts"
        },
        '*.less': { loader: 'less' }
    }

  });
})(this);
```

And this is my component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['profile.less']  
})
export class ProfileComponent {

}
```

And my SystemJS import in index.html

```
<script>            
    SystemJS.import('systemjs.config.js')
        .then(function () {
            SystemJS.import('main');
        })
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));            

    </script>
```

If I import my less file in the index.html with this, it works: SystemJS.import('./app/profile/profile.less!less');
So I guess the plugin works.

But I don't think it's the way it should be done, the meta configuration in systemjs.config.js is here to avoid us specifying each les file, right ?

styleUrls: ['profile.less'] in my component ts file also works since I see the css is used, but less parts (like variables) of the file are ignored.

Thank you

Comment: Same is happening with me, did you get any solution to this problem ?